# Gain Internet access with multiple networks configured

Tags: networking, wifi, routing, networkmanager, ethernet

I'm running Ubuntu 21.10 and NetworkManager. I have some difficulties to configure my networks.
This is the scenario:

- WiFi, to connect to the local access-point and to provide Internet access
- Ethernet #1, configured with static address, to connect to a specific device (i.e. HDMI splitter)
- Ethernet #2, configured with DHCP and fallback with static address:

  - it may be connected to the same router of the WiFi
  - or may be connected to a PC (w/ static address) to provide SSH access to the machine

The first issue is this use case:

- WiFi connected
- either Ethernet #1 or #2 connected to a device/PC with static addresss

In this situation, the machine is not connected to the Internet anymore. The pings fail with either DNS or IP query.

What I have to do in order to use WiFi for Internet and the other(s) networks for LAN access only?

Comment: Without any details it's not possible to give concrete answers. However, I'd start by checking there is only one default gateway defined

Comment: @roaima feel free to ask any detail I can share. I'm not sure what it's relevant or not. In the meanwhile I'm searching how to check if there is only one default gateway defined.

Comment: `netstat -rn` or `ip route`

Comment: @roaima yep, it was the gateway